# Unable to read text in dynamic webtable in "Div" tags

Tags: java, html

In this I have to read the green highlighted text but when we mouse hover on the series that time the yellow highlighted text will display from country to indicator. I have tried with below xpath but Selenium is not recognizing, could you please suggest any other xpaths.

Our code is like below.

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
WebElement we =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='series-list-item-data']"));
act.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
System.out.println("elements "+we);
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='series-list-item-data']"));
int total_count=list.size();
for(int i = 0; i < total_count; i++){
    System.out.println("list size"+list.size());
    WebElement element=list.get(i);
    String text=element.getAttribute("class");
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: After googling , i got some information on mouse hover and that code is able to get the results for only one web element but failed to move to next element. So kindly help on how to get the list of web element using mouse hover. you can find the code in the below comments

Comment: Code as below Actions act=new Actions(login.driver);
    WebElement we =login.driver.findElement(By.className("series-list-item"));
    act.moveToElement(we).click().build().perform();
   List<WebElement> list=we.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='series-list-item-data']"));
   System.out.println("Total number of series are displayed in first page :"+list.size());  
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     WebElement element=list.get(i);
     String text=element.getAttribute("title");
     System.out.println("Tool tip text is present  "+text);
    }